# Can I get data from server when I clicked the static table cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Can I get data from server when I clicked the static table cell?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.textLabel?.text = firstDay
        } else if indexPath.row == 1{
            cell.textLable?.text = secondDay
        }... // It have 7 row and 7 days
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0{
        retrieveTime()
    }
}
```

I'm posting this format to get data, How I can get the selected cell label text and put it on the parameter(jobDate)..?

```
func retrieveTime(){
    let param = ["action": "retrieve time", "job": ["crew_id": crewID, "jobDate": firstDay]] as [String : Any]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of jobDate in didselect method and then pass it as parameter to the retrieveTime method.

E.g.:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0{
      let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

      jobDateValue = selectedCell.textLabel!.text! 
      retrieveTime(jobDateValue)
          }
     }
```

Comment: Do not do this. Get the data from the data model, not the cell.

Comment: I got "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments” error at retrieveTime(jobDateValue)

Comment: func retrieveTime(){  }  should be changed to func retrieveTime(jobDateValue: String) -> Void

Comment: @rmaddy : Thanks for suggesting this. Wan, you can take the value from your tableview datasource(Array) instead of cell for the same indexpath position

Comment: @SeemaNair how to take it from datasource array? btw your code is worked.

Comment: Hi Wan, Thank you.  Are you using any array or any other data source in this method - cellForRowAt?